# Why does trigger.new and trigger.old return a list?

Tags: apex

It seems like it should return a set instead, but it returns a list. Why is that?

Comment: If you used a set, presumably you couldn't then have two identical records in the insertion/update list. The difference between two records may just be the ID, which of course will not be present prior to an insert

Comment: Also a list is ordered, and it is very often useful to be able to compare the values of old and new during trigger processing, which you can do by comparing old[x] with new[x]

Comment: Why do you think it should return a set?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefit of returning a set, in general sets aren't well designed for objects, and are better used with primitives ... whyat were you expecting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several reasons for this:

### Sets have Collisions

In a set, you can't have duplicate values. This means that if someone did this:

```
insert new Account[] { new Account(Name='Test'), new Account(Name='Test') };
```

Trigger.new would contain only one entry in a before insert trigger.

```
Set<Account> accs = new Set<Account>{ new Account(Name='Test'), new Account(Name='Test') };
System.assertEquals(1, accs.size());
```

### Sets are Unordered

Trigger.new and Trigger.old are ordered in the same way, so that you can guarantee Trigger.new[12] matches Trigger.old[12].

You wouldn't be able to compare old and new values directly without resorting to trigger.newmap and trigger.oldmap (which before insert would again have problems with).

You can't do this with a set:

```
for(Integer index = 0; index < Trigger.new.size(); index++) {
    // Compare Trigger.new[index] and Trigger.old[index]
}
```

Comment: After [they managed to screw up Id uniqueness](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36372/duplicate-ids) (granted, "only" in queries) I've developed some serious FUD about this... I think your comment about "before insert" should say "after insert" ("before" is empty) - in which case I agree, if ever order of old & new becomes unreliable - we're screwed in "after insert".

Comment: @sfdcfox-  on the insert example above, wouldn't they be unique at time of insert because they have unique IDs?

Comment: @nivyaj In a *before insert* trigger, the ID values are blank, because the server hasn't had a commit yet, so the auto-generated ID values don't exist yet. That means that a *before insert trigger* set would result in a collapse of the records.

Comment: @eyescream No, I meant *before insert*-- Trigger.newMap doesn't work because it references values by ID, which are still null. Trigger.newMap works normally in *after insert*, but that does cripple our ability to perform certain types of optimizations that are thankfully rare.

Comment: But before insert the trigger.old(Map) is useless, you have nothing to compare against. So "before insert" isn't a good example here I think.

Comment: @eyescream Hmm.. I think I need to rework that section. The lack of an ID means that you can't create another record that will be also linked to the original record without calling at least one "update" call. Say we have objects A, and B, with B having lookup to A, and A to B. If ID values were present before insert, we could create a B during a create to A and link them together during create. But we can't, so we end up with a recursive call (after insert->after update).

Answer (score 1):

A list is ordered, and it is very often useful to be able to compare the values of old and new during trigger processing, which you can do by comparing old[x] with new[x]

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36390/is-the-order-of-records-the-same-in-the-trigger-new-list-in-before-and-after-tri

Comment: @eyescream That code refers to a *query*. Trigger.old[x] will correspond to Trigger.new[x].